# uicollectionview and searchbar cell height after search

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a `search bar` below that I have `collection view`. So when I search something and after scrolling the display results shows wrong value and it happens because of `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight`. But when I delete `this(UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight)`, it shows right result but the last cell get cut off. I am not using auto layout.

Below is the image of storyboard view controller:

[image]

Comment: add code for search and tableview methods

Comment: did u understand my problem with that collectionview cell??